# How to intercept Navigator.pop and block navigation back conditionally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to intercept navigation **back** conditionally.

User/server can modify global state of the app like authentication, causing page to navigate to login form, but when user navigates to screen A then presses **back button** twice, user is still able to see widgets that are supposed to be available only for logged in session.

I've tried all I could thought of:

- onGenerateRoute in MaterialApp but it's not triggered when back button is pressed
- WillPop is a solution to that, but all top-level widgets would have to be wrapped in it and I need to remember to pass auth state to all the widgets, it's not really scalable solution, but could work
- `navigatorObservers` is notified about Navigator.pop events seems not to be able to prevent navigation

Ideally, would like to avoid 3rd party dependencies with hooks on every widget like back_button_interceptor.

It should also work with statelesswidgets, where `dispose()` method is not available.

Is there any way to get something like single class/point of failure "navigator interceptor" which would return true/false and be able to modify route in flight based on a condition?

Answer (score 3):

Looking into the implementation of WillPopScope, it makes use of the addScopedWillPopCallback() function of the ModalRoute.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/addScopedWillPopCallback.html

If you implemented a router with onGenerateRoute it should be possible to add an universal check for every route you push. Maybe you could even make a customized Route class inherited from MaterialPageRoute that includes that logic.

If i understood your problem right,i feel like intercepting back navigation is the wrong approach. I would rather try to remove the unauthorized pages from the navigation stack when navigating back to the login screen with Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()

Comment: Yes, that's quite good enough for now. It helped a lot thanks! I wish there was `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveWHEN()` so I can put a set{} of route names to remove from the tree, but this does a job good enough.

Comment: @agilob can always implement an extension